# Rstudio en ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, rstudio

Actualice a ubuntu 22 y rstudio ya no funciona. Leí en algunos foros que aun no hay solución. ¿Alguien mas que le haya pasado lo mismo y me pueda sugerir algo?

Comment: Has revisado los logs de ubuntu? Algún error que valga la pena añadir a la pregunta? "No funciona" es una mala descripción de cualquier problema. Por favor ve a [edit] y amplía los detalles de tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, [aquí](https://docs.rstudio.com/rsw/requirements/) dice que sí soportan Ubuntu 22, entonces no es evidente nada de lo que contiene la pregunta y hace difícil ayudar

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/installation-of-rstudio-on-ubuntu-22-04lts/138458/3 descarga el .deb e instala con `sudo apt install ./rstudio*.deb`

Comment: gracias Alo, si se soluciono instalándolo de nuevo